# crashed postgres database in artifactory

Tags: postgresql, artifactory, jfrog-cli

we have an artifactory (5.6.2) running on docker with a postgres (9.6.6-alpine) also on docker. 
We realized that artifactory performed very badly so i looked at the containers and saw that postgres was taking all cpu it could get.
So tried to restart the postgres but it did fail:

```
23.2.2018 11:28:12PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
23.2.2018 11:28:12LOG:  startup process (PID 20) was terminated by signal 6
23.2.2018 11:28:12LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
23.2.2018 11:28:12LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I then restored the whole DB Folder from Backup and tried to restart the DB again. The Postgres DB came up but as i started artifactory its waiting at the point:

```
23.2.2018 15:03:392018-02-23 15:03:39,537 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:91) - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Starting JFrog Access bootstrap...
23.2.2018 15:03:392018-02-23 15:03:39,576 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:164) - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Updating server ....
```

So Artifactory communicates with the DB and the DB again eats up all CPU.

Is this normal ? This situation is running for an hour or so, can somebody tell me if this ever stops successfully.

Do i have any other options besides waiting or has someone a tip for me how i can get my artifactory up and running again.

Every help is welcome.

thanks

Comment: You should see what the database is doing. Looking into the log file would help.

Comment: Log says:
"LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
23.2.2018 15:00:24LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
23.2.2018 15:03:25LOG:  incomplete startup packet"

and then nothing.... :-(

Comment: I am able to connect with pg-admin - and i see two artifactory sessions.
one is in LWLockTranche: lock_manager state

Comment: Try and add this finding to the question. Can you connect to the backend with gdb and get a stack trace?

Comment: In the end it turned out that the db corrupted and was simply destroyed. This was achieved having 2 cloned vms.